# How can I make Supervisor run on a different port than the default 6001?

Tags: laravel, supervisor

I have a laravel project and I am using Laravel-Websockets which run under the port 6001. However, I'm installing Supervisor to help run commands automatically, but the Supervisor is running on the same 6001 port and I get
`Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:6001": Address already in use (EADDRINUSE)`

Is there any way to change the Supervisor and make it run under another port? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What version?

Comment: Hi David I found a solution. Changing Websockets to port 6002 and clearing the cache is doing a great job